# PCA on wavelet subbands

Tags: signal-processing, pca, wavelet

I guess that PCA cannot be applied on vectors, however I found some papers that apply PCA on each of the wavelet subbands as in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6949361/) and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267104468_Wavelet_Based_Machine_Learning_Techniques_for_Electrocardiogram_Signal_Analysis). As wavelet subbands are vectors, how is it possible to apply PCA on them?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The papers you mention are about EEG and ECG signals, which are also (1D) vectors. Multiple signals together for one subject (or a group) are a matrix. That's what how the PCA runs on input EEG signals.

You can do the same with a wavelet transform. A wavelet subband of a 1D signal is still a 1D signal, but you can group them together in matrices. Then you can run PCA in the same way as on the input data.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I hope it helps! I didn't go into details because they differ between various types of transforms. In the fast wavelet transform the subbands are a factor 2 shorter at each level, in others they keep the same length.